# unity Game Center login dialog not shown again after cancelling

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, xamarin.ios

I have a problem with logging a user to the Game Center. I first present the login dialog right after the application finishes loading. If the user cancels the dialog. the button doesn't do anything - the Game Center dialog doesn't get shown.I immediately get the error

error Code:-

> _authenticateUsingAlert: Failed to authenticate player with existing credentials.Error: Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=6 "The requested operation could not be completed because the local player has not been authenticated." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The requested operation could not be completed because the local player has not been authenticated

```
Social.localUser.Authenticate(success => {
            if (success)
                Debug.Log("success authenticate");
            else
                Debug.Log("Failed to authenticate");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer for your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21132075

> Important: Game Kit handles opting out of Game Center across all games that support Game Center. **If a player has already declined to create an account, when your game authenticates the player, it is told there is no authenticated player. The player never sees an authentication dialog.** Because Game Kit handles this process across all games, your game should not include its own mechanism to disable Game Center authentication or ask a player’s permission to authenticate. Instead, your game should simply authenticate the player every time it launches and respond appropriately when authentication completes.